# *ngFor over Pug/Jade mixin

Tags: angular, pug

I'm developing menu for my application and have something like this:

**MenuItem class**

```
class MenuItem implements Serializable<MenuItem>{
  name: string;
  link: string;
  styles: string;
  children: MenuItem[];
}
```

**Component:**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'side-navbar',
  styleUrls: [ 'side-navbar.component.sass' ],
  templateUrl: 'side-navbar.component.pug',
})
export class SideNavbarComponent {
  public menuItems: MenuItem[];

  constructor() {
    this.menuItems = [];
  }
}
```

**PUG Template:**

```
mixin menuItem(element)
  li.menu-item(style=element.styles)
    a(routerLink= element.link routerLinkActive="active")= element.name
      each child in element.children
        +menuItem(child)

div.sidebar-container(layout="row")
  .sidebar-body
    ul
      +menuItem(child)(*ngFor="let child of menuItems")
```

I have no idea how to handle the last template line.
I want there display mixin for each element in MenuItem.
But the browser said that there is no 'size' of undefined - so there is no bounding between compnent and template. Help

Comment: Is it something to do with the fact, you are referencing your PUG template and SASS stylesheet in your component, when you should reference there compiled forms ie CSS for SASS?

Comment: Component is in TS file so during processing to JS, PUG refernece is changing to HTML reference.